# Splitting an input String

Tags: java, string

I've the following Query String,

```
QUERY 192.168.1.0 0 2016-08-25 18:32 2016-08-26 18:31
```

I want to split it into 5 string objects such that `2016-08-25 18:32` and `2016-08-26 18:31` are parsed as one object.

```
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
```

Splits the String into 7 strings splitting the dates. I'm not sure how to do it using regular expressions using Java.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would do this manually. Split into 7, then combine the last 4 into 2.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. But surely there must be a better way.

Comment: Define better: faster? shorter? simpler? There is no universal "better".

Comment: Better == More elegant

Comment: Now, define elegant. shorter? better formatted? code shaped like a puppy?

Comment: Code shaped like a puppy is the best option among the provided.

Comment: I would say your approach is simple and effective - the very definition of elegance. A regex pattern has the "write once, read never" problem - if I give you some fancy regex, you'll forget what it does in a matter of hours. If I come up with puppy shaped code, I'll let your know - for now though, how about [this](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-perl-737.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as the positions of the items are static, simply manipulate your output array after the split:

```
String sdate = arr[3] + ' ' + arr[4];
String edate = arr[5] + ' ' + arr[6];
```

if needed, make a new array:

```
String[] arr2 = {arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], sdate, edate};
```

good luck!

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but isn't there a better way to do using regex.

Comment: i don't know about 'better' -- regex is always a tradeoff.  but if you're just looking for a regex to pull the values, you could try: `([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+ [^ ]+) ([^ ]+ [^ ]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Another short and cool way to achieve the above is by splitting the string by space onto a new line using regex.

`str.replaceAll("\\s", "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You totally don't need a RegEx here. Parsing a string with regex is a rather complex process, and in your situation where you have static positions in string and can just concatenate parts - regex is an obvious overkill.

And by the way, regexes almost always make your code much less readable. So with regex here you will end up with a lot less readable and performant code.

Vote against RegEx.